# nginx-rtmp-module -- unknown directive "dash_variant"

Tags: nginx, mpeg-dash

I'm running into a strange issue with a dash application in nginx. Everything works okay if I don't include the dash_variant lines in the code below. The second I uncomment them, the nginx config fails with `unknown directive "dash_variant"`. I'm looking to add the `dash_variant` directives so I can have different bitrate streams depending on quality of the user's bandwidth/connection. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
                     application dash {
                                allow play all;
                                live on;
                                #record all;
                                record off;
                                record_path videos;
                                record_unique on;
                                #allow publish <your_sender_ip_here>;
                                #allow publish 127.0.0.1;
                                #deny publish all;
                                meta copy;
                                wait_key on;
                                wait_video on;
                                idle_streams off;

                                # Dash settings and pushing towards repeaters
                                dash on;
                                dash_nested on;
                                dash_path /tmp/dash;
                                dash_fragment 3;
                                dash_playlist_length 20;
                                dash_cleanup on;

                                #dash_clock_compensation http_head;
                                #dash_clock_helper_uri https://localhost/time;

                                dash_variant _low bandwidth="500000"  width="640"  height="360";
                                dash_variant _med bandwidth="1500000" width="1280"  height="720";
                                dash_variant _high bandwidth="5000000" width="1920" height="1080" max;

                                #push rtmp://localhost/hls/hls; // it goes to generate a HLS streaming
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, **dash_variant** is not supported according to docs. If you want to use **dash_variant** you can build nginx with [this](https://libraries.io/github/chetandhembre/nginx-rtmp-module) module which is enhanced version of actual module.

[RTMP DIRECTIVES](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#hls_variant)